# Entityframework Core - Queries are executed fast but SaveChanges complete way after

Tags: performance, entity-framework-core

In my current task, I'm trying to insert 100 users with approx 20 properties. Logger shows me EF Core executing all these insertion processes by dividing to 4 different queries and each query execution takes up to 100ms. Even though all queries are executed under 1 second, it takes around 10 seconds application code to step over `SaveChanges`.

Things that are considered and implemented:

- There is only a single `SaveChanges` call.
- There are no additional relations with the user object. Single entity, single table.
- All mapping validated couple times to match entity property types with column types.

For a low record number such as 100, this is unacceptable as you may agree.

Which direction should I look at to understand the underlying problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO! To increase the likelihood of a helpful answer, please provide us with some snippets of the code in question

Comment: Please tell us more about the database and server you are using. Is this a local database? Is it SQL Server? If it is not local, have you tried it against a local instance? If you insert much fewer users, say 25, does it take only 25% of the original time, or longer?